# How to connect iOS app to Wordpress?

Tags: ios, wordpress, swift

I have a website on Wordpress that has users which login. This is my first project connecting to another database that is not Parse or Firebase.

How would it be possible to get all the information from that website (users/posts ... etc) and make it available on my iPhone.

The app is technically a Pinterest clone.

I want to be able to login to my app through my iPhone. Wordpress has a REST API but not sure how to put them together.

Comment: When did WordPress get a REST API?

Comment: *shrug* no clue , never messed with wordpress until my first iOS project is too connect them together!

Comment: Follow the instructions in this http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Comment: @neoprez I saw that yesterday. I wouldnt really know where to go from there. Is there any example code that can show me more or less how to get it done?

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever get a suitable solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The Official Wordpress app for iOS has the code for it Open source and available on Github at this link . . . 
https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS

Hopefully that will help!

Comment: going to check it out now, I will keep ya posted !